Switching generic kernel to server kernel
I am setting up an ubuntu server with nginx. It will be load balancer and reverse proxy.
As far as I understand my ubuntu distrubition is Server.
in var/log/installer/media-info result;

Ubuntu-Server 22.04.3 LTS "Jammy Jellyfish" - Release amd64 (20230810)

uname -a result ;

Linux app.example.com 5.15.0-112-generic #122-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 23 07:48:21 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

the installation file is ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
it runs on vmware
But according to articles(AFAIK) I am using generic kernel.
Should I switch on Server Kernel? if yes how can I convert it to server kernel?
btw I do not completely understand what the difference between generic-kernel and server-kernel. Link

The Server by default uses the GA kernel stack; which is 5.15.  The HWE kernel stack is 6.5 currently for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which is the default for the Desktop system.. The term generic relates to something else (ie. it's not a low-latency or OEM kernel.. but the generic kernel & 5.15 tells you its GA which is the default Server kernel)

FYI:   You do not want the linux-image-server package as far as I can see; ie. I see only linux-image-server | 3.13.0.170.181 | trusty-security | amd64, i386 as being available...   which does fit the 2012-08-09 last-update of the page you provided...   You're using the correct kernel as I see it.

Thanks @guiverc . is there any performance difference between these packages? Should I go with this installation? do you mean that  no need to change the kernel for server usage?

trusty was 14.04 - you do not want that... The GA kernel stack is seen as the most stable, and is default as Server installs usually prize stability...  The HWE kernel stack is newer and can benefit users of newer hardware (esp. in relation to graphics hardware... why it's default on Desktop installs), and low-latency is usually prized by people creating audio/video (but drawbacks of it usually aren't ideal for servers; why it's not default there)

The Server by default uses the GA kernel stack; which is 5.15.  The HWE kernel stack is 6.5 currently for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which is the default for the Desktop system..
The term generic relates to something else (ie. it's not a low-latency or OEM kernel.. but the generic kernel & 5.15 tells you its GA which is the default Server kernel)
FYI:   You do not want the linux-image-server package as far as I can see; ie. I see only
linux-image-server | 3.13.0.170.181 | trusty-security | amd64, i386
as being available...   which does fit the 2012-08-09 last-update of the page you provided...  See bottom right where it states "last edited 2012-09-09 17:09:30"
You're using the correct kernel as far as I see it  (your alternative is really the newer HWE kernel stack used by Desktop installs, but Servers are usually better using the more stable GA kernel stack that is default)

To learn more about the HWE kernel stack (as an option to the GA default stack for Servers) you can read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack ...  There is also mention of OEM there; but it's usually useful only when the installer detects you'll benefit from it during install (thus it gets installed)
